# 'setCodecPreferences' function 'RTCRtpTransceiver' is removed in TypeScript Version 4.5.5

Tags: javascript, typescript, webrtc

The following code was compiling successfully on TypeScript version 3.5.0

```
private SetCodecPreferences (transceiver: RTCRtpTransceiver):
void
{
    transceiver.setCodecPreferences(PREFERRED_VIDEO_CODECS); //PREFERRED_VIDEO_CODECS is of type RTCRtpCodecCapability[]
}
```

After updating to TypeScript version 4.5.5, we are getting the below error message

> error TS2339: Property 'setCodecPreferences' does not exist on type
> 'RTCRtpTransceiver'

[TypeScript 4.4 libdom changes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator/issues/1029) suggest that function *'setCodecPreferences'* is removed in TypeScript 4.4 but not finding any reason. [image]

I have 2 questions

1. How to fix the above issue or Do we have any alternatives? other than (*transceiver as any*)
2. Is there any way where we can build code based on 'TypeScript' version i.e. if 'Typescript' version is bellow 4.4 execute specific lines of code, else other.